# Using mat-expansion-panel in dialog causes scroll to bottom of page

Tags: angular

When displaying a dialog (with dialog.open) that contains a `<mat-expansion-panel>`, I find that the browser scrolls this panel into view, if it is at the bottom of the page.

It seems to be a problem both in Chrome and IE.
I've tried setting `expanded="false"` to no avail.

Please see the example in this stackblitz

https://angular-efsxjw.stackblitz.io

In the example, when you click "click", the page is scrolled to the expansion panel (although a dialog is not opened, which is a stackblitz issue, I assume)

`EDIT:`
Seems to be the `<mat-expansion-panel-header>` that is causing the problem. 
I have added a hidden mat-expansion-panel-header to the top of the page that takes focus.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same issue. Have you written up a bug against the Angular Material repo?

Comment: FYI, Stackblitz won't load your example for some reason.

Comment: I opened an issue with @angular/material on GitHub
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19630
Here is a current stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uk31wr

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a bug. This is desired behavior that can be overridden. The dialog has a focus trap to focus the first focusable element automatically.

To override this you simply add `{ autoFocus: false }` to the dialog's open call.

`dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, { autoFocus: false });`

StackBlitz showing both the problem and solution:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uk31wr